# Android AsynkTask problem with HttpUtilities class

Tags: android

I want to tell you about the structure of my classes.

I have an HttpUtilities class, from which I am doing requests(send and get JSON objects) to server. It's a public class with private constructor and static methods.

I have also user class which manipulates data(set string to JSON, and JSON to ...).

Within my activity I have declared the instance of user class.
There are some methods(SignIn, SignOut, InserToListView) there which call corresponding methods of httpUtilities.

Now, I want, that for each event of user, using AsynkTask do request to server and change ui.
I want to call method(for example InserToListview) of user class within new Thread using AsynkTask.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you tried your hand at this first and then asked questions later, but here is some general advice to get you started:

1. Subclass `AsyncTask`.
2. Implement `doInBackground`, calling your insert method.
3. (Wherever you are calling your insert method now) instantiate your subclass of `AsyncTask`.
4. Call the `execute` method on your new custom `AsyncTask` object.
5. Store your `AsyncTask` in an instance variable so you can `cancel` it later on.